# PHP url validation + detection

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So here is what I need to do.

If an user enters this: `http://site.com` I need to remove `http://` so the string will be `site.com` , if an user enters `http://www.site.com` I need to remove `http://www.` or if the user enters `www.site.com` I need to remove `www.` or he can also enter `site.com` it will be good as well.

I have a function here, but doesn't work how I want to, and I suck at regex.

```
preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $_POST['link'])
```

Comment: just want to notice, that sometimes "domain.tld" is not the same as "www.domain.tld"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I'd use regex for this, since you're only really checking for what is at the beginning of the string.  So:

```
$link = $_POST['link'];
if (stripos($link, 'http://') === 0)
{
    $link = substr($link, 7);
}
elseif (stripos($link, 'https://') === 0)
{
    $link = substr($link, 8);
}
if (stripos($link, 'www.') === 0)
{
    $link = substr($link, 4);
}
```

should take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) instead.

```
if (filter_var($_POST['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    // valid URL
} else {
   // not valid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also [parse_url](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

i always go with str_replace haha

```
str_replace('http://','',str_replace('www.','',$url))
```

Comment: If there happens to be another 'www.' in the string except at the beginning, this approach would have a problem.

Comment: Removing of "www." can be a problem in any case ;-)

Comment: alrighty, how bout this
str_replace('http://www.','',str_replace('http://','',$url))

Comment: @Ascherer You would never reach the outer str_replace with anything that it would replace if the original $url is valid.  You would already have stripped off the http://.

Comment: yeah, i did it backwards, im gonna stop commenting on this one cause im getting tired, but u get the picture, just a simple way, that with work, could also be used.

Comment: Though i dont know why a www. would appear twice in a url anyways

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a multi-stage `preg_replace()`:

```
$tmp = strtolower($_POST['link']) ;
$tmp = preg_replace('/^http(s)?/', '', $tmp);
$domain = preg_replace('/^www./', '', $tmp) ;
```

This simplifies the required regex quite a bit too.